# Purpose of Vega Hedging

Tags: options, trading, hedging, gamma, vega

I am trying to understand the principle of vega hedging.

When should a market maker vega hedge his position ?

Let's suppose that a market maker delta and gamma hedge himself, and carries his position (combination of Calls, Puts, Underlying) until maturity: does a change in volatility affects his P&L at maturity ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Because even when you gamma hedge you will need to periodically rebalance the option you use for the gamma hedge. As you rebalance you get hit by the vega p/l.

Comment: And then when you think you are safe with delta gamma and vega hedge you get hit by vanna and volga.

Comment: Ok it makes sense ! Thanks